# Recommended Processor

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

I recently bought a GTX 1080 Founders Edition that I'm connecting to an ASUS ATX ROG STRIX X99 Gaming Board. I've heard that the new [Intel i7 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz) would a good buy, but are there any other good gaming processors that would go well with my current equipment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to be overclocking (though if you have that system, *why wouldn't you be overclocking* is likely a better question), then the **[Intel Xeon E5-1620 V4](http://www.superbiiz.com/detail.php?name=E51620V4BX&c=CJ)** is a better gaming processor than the Intel Core i7-5820K or the Intel Core i7-6800K. Those processors feature more cores and threads but lower clock speeds, and games don't yet really need more than eight threads. The lower price on the E5-1620 v4 is nice too.

The only real downside here is that this is a locked processor, so you won't have any ability to overclock. If for some reason you're not going to be doing that, then by all means get the Xeon mentioned above.